# how to get path of text file inside File.rar in c#

Tags: c#

Currently my application can access file inside a normal folder but it can not access file inside a zip folder so i want to know how can i get full access path of text file inside a zip file in windows application

Following Code:

```
ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(openFileDialog1.FileName);
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(entry.FullName);
}
```

Comment: `.rar` is a differen format than `.zip`. You need to find a .NET library that can read `.rar` files. Zip files can be processed using the [ZipPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.zippackage?view=netframework-4.7.2) class or [ZipFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: you say "it can not access file".  please post an brief block of your code that is not working, and what error or result you are getting.

Comment: Are you trying to read a zip file or a rar one? The title says one thing and the question says another.

Comment: both @Alejandro

Comment: @wasifkhan Then you'll need to use *both* zip and rar libraries, according to the file type in question. You're already handling zip, but rar will fail.